# UPDATE records from SELECT using a case statement. (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, case

I am trying to update a collection of records using a case statement but I get:

> error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'FROM( SELECT SoftwareProjects.id,
>   SoftwareProjects.Project_Code, `Description`' at line 8

here is my query:

```sql
UPDATE SoftwareProjects
SET BudgetStatus =
CASE
WHEN ((HoursBooked/HoursEstimated) * (100/1) < 80) THEN 1
WHEN ((HoursBooked/HoursEstimated) * (100/1) > 81 && (HoursBooked/HoursEstimated) * (100/1) < 100 ) THEN 2
ELSE   3
END
FROM
(SELECT SoftwareProjects.id, SoftwareProjects.Project_Code,  Description,
        BudgetStatus,  TimelineStatus,  QualityStatus,  OverallStatus,
        DeliveryDate,  HoursEstimated,  s4_project_id, 
        SUM( hours_adjusted ) AS HoursBooked
                        FROM SoftwareProjects
                        LEFT JOIN S4Admin.ts_entries ON s4_project_id = 
                        S4Admin.ts_entries.project
                        GROUP BY Description
                        ORDER BY  SoftwareProjects.Description)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below

```
UPDATE SoftwareProjects a
  JOIN
  (SELECT SoftwareProjects.id, SoftwareProjects.Project_Code,  Description,  BudgetStatus,  TimelineStatus,  QualityStatus,  OverallStatus,  DeliveryDate,  HoursEstimated,  s4_project_id, SUM( hours_adjusted ) AS HoursBooked
                          FROM SoftwareProjects
                          LEFT JOIN S4Admin.ts_entries ON s4_project_id = 
                          S4Admin.ts_entries.project
                          GROUP BY Description
                          ORDER BY  SoftwareProjects.Description) b on a.id=b.id

SET a.BudgetStatus =
  CASE
  WHEN ((HoursBooked/b.HoursEstimated) * (100/1) < 80) THEN 1
  WHEN ((HoursBooked/b.HoursEstimated) * (100/1) > 81 && (HoursBooked/b.HoursEstimated) * (100/1) < 100 ) THEN 2
  ELSE   3
  END
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm now getting "#1052 - Column 'HoursEstimated' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: @cyberghost47, modified the answer you can  check now